# Getting itextsharp to keep the text flow

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Currently, when I open my pdf in reader/acrobat, it recognizes the fact that there are columns, in that text flows from the bottom of one column to the top of another.

How can I get itextreader to keep this flow, as opposed to reading from left to right in all cases?

Comment: I assume you are talking about text extraction using the classes from the *.parser  namespace. Most likely you are using the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. This strategy assumes that the order in which text drawing operations appear in the content stream are not related to the reading order and, therefore, have to be sorted by position. Are the assumptions correct?

Comment: One thing you can easily try is using the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` instead; this strategy assumes the order in which text drawing operations appear in the content stream is the trading order.

Comment: Ah, i love writing on smart phones. Not *trading* but *reading* of course.